# Redirecionamento de "dominio.com.br" para "subdominio.xyz.com.br"

Tags: linux, servidor, ubuntu, redirecionamento

Estou com um problema de redirecionamento/apontamento e acredito que seja alguma configuração de servidor incorreta. Possuo uma VPS (digital ocean) rodando Ubuntu14 (terminal) com Apache, PHP5, MySql. Possuo total acesso as configurações de DNS dessa VPS e dos domínios (Registro.br).

O problema é o seguinte: 
- Possuo o dominio: http://etiquetasribeirao.com.br no registro.br
- Possuo o seguinte subdominio na VPS: http://etiquetasribeirao.netshops.com.br

**Quero que ao acessar o dominio seja exibido o site do subdominio, tipo um apontamento, mantendo na barra de endereço do browser, o dominio original acessado.**

Já configurei no "registro.br" o registro CNAME mas sem sucesso.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Obrigado.

Comment: Boa tarde, Você pode usar o mod_proxy do apache para fazer isso. Já conhece este modulo do apache?

Comment: Aconselho tirar o domínio real da sua postagem. Vai que postando código aqui, fica público alguma informação útil a alguém mal-intencionado...

Answer (score 1):

No arquivo de configurações do apache, onde você configurou o servidor o `VirtualHost` (trecho similar ao código abaixo) do `etiquetasribeirao.netshops.com.br`, você deve criar um `ServerAlias` conforme está abaixo:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName etiquetasribeirao.netshops.com.br
  ServerAlias etiquetasribeirao.com.br 
...
```

E no registro.br você deve criar um registro tipo A (Host) no dominio `etiquetasribeirao.com.br` apontando para o IP do seu servidor `etiquetasribeirao.netshops.com.br`.

Answer (score 0):

Você não vai conseguir resolver isso com DNS. Mesmo que você aceitasse que o primeiro nome fosse trocado pelo segundo na barra do browser, não é recomendado fazer CNAME de um domínio. CNAME é para subdomínios, e.g. para um netshops.etiquetasribeirao.com.br redirecionar para etiquetasribeirao.netshops.com.br, quando não existe nenhum outro registro DNS para o nome, e o nome de topo de domínio sempre tem registros (SOA, NS, ...)

Para que um site mantenha o nome da barra, mas mostre partes de outros, você pode usar iframe, ou proxy do lado servidor (mod_proxy no caso do Apache, conforme comentário do Adriano Salles).

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do escopo `VirtualHost`, acrescente:

```
ServerAlias etiquetasribeirao.netshops.com.br
```

logo abaixo do `servername etiquetasribeirao.com.br`.